# pixi.js - erase from rendertexture

Tags: pixi.js

I'm wondering how I can erase from the rendertexture. e.g. I fill a rectangle and then want to make a circle in the center transparent again.

I tried drawing stuff with alpha 0 and using various blendmodes. I was actually looking for a BlendMode.None of some sort to copy the alpha channel directly, but there's only BlendMode.Normal, which doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: Any updates to this?